How to fix 15: exec: node: not found in a NodeJS project with Typescript on Windows?
I'm new to Nodejs and Typescript and facing a problem on a Windows machine. I set up an empty project with a single index.ts just for testing. I'm also using nodemon.
When I use tsc command to generate js files from ts, it works without any error and the files are built in the build directory.

But when I want to do that using the node's start script (using nodemon), it throws an error.
Any ideas why it happens and how to fix it?

Node, ts-node, tsc are installed:

Here is my package.json:
{
  "name": "signal-service",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tsconfig/node20": "^20.1.4",
    "@types/node": "^22.7.7",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.7",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3"
  }
}

Here is my tsconfig.json:
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node20/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build"
  ]
}

Here is my nodemon.json:
{
  "watch": [
    "src"
  ],
  "ext": "js,ts,json",
  "exec": "ts-node ./src/index.ts"
}

I tried reinstall node on my machine and set up a project from scratch a few times.

Have you tried to use cmd.exe instead of PowerShell? There are issues using PowerShell on Windows in my experience.
First, try run the same folder in cmd.exe. If it works, then replace your Webstorm's terminal with cmd or even git bash. This is an instruction how to do it: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/terminal-emulator.html#open-terminal

I've just tried both cmd.exe and git bash. The problem persists with cmd.exe but it's working as it shoud when using git bash. Thanks!
